# vba TRUE or FALSE text from Clipboard recognised as boolean by Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, clipboard, string

I have table with one of the column (let say column Code) has text TRUE in it. But, when I copy it to excel, the data become boolen so my vlookup (that search text TRUE from column code) become an error (#N/A). How do I solve this..?

FYI, I insert data to clipboard first

```vb
Dim ClipboardObj As New MSForms.DataObject
ClipboardObj.SetText Text:=myExternalData
ClipboardObj.PutInClipboard
```

Then input the data to excel table using paste special

```vb
Range("C4").Select
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

Comment: What is the format of cell C4? Before and after the commands are executed. Do you want TRUE as a string and not a boolean?

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I change the format of Code Column to Text in Excel toolbar
I forgot to check the format.

@njc: yes, I want text "TRUE" as string (not boolean) after paste it from clipboard.

Comment: Sorry Loki, didn't see you already solved your question.

Answer (score 0):

In your VBA code, set the cell format to text,

```
Range("C4").NumberFormat = "@"
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

If you require double quotes around the TRUE cell value,

```
Range("C4").NumberFormat = "@"  ' you may not need this
ActiveSheet.PasteSpecial Format:="Text", Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=False
Range("C4").Value = Chr(34) + Range("C4").Value + Chr(34)
```